# BehaviorSpace Netlogo- Measure runs using these reporters

Tags: netlogo

I am simulating a classroom and calculating the energy consumed by lights, fans and ACs. Now I am running my simulation in behavior space so that after each run the energy consumed is shown. The energy consumed is in a procedure.

```
to energy-calculation

ask lights [ ifelse ( l-on? )  [ set l-energy (light-on-duration * light- 
wattage) ][ set l-energy 0 ] ]
ask fans [ ifelse ( f-on? ) [ set f-energy ( fan-on-duration * fan-wattage 
)] [ set f-energy 0 ] ]
ask acs [ ifelse ( a-on? ) [ set a-energy (ac-on-duration * ac-wattage) ] [ 
set a-energy 0 ] ]

let light-e sum [l-energy] of lights
let fan-e sum [f-energy] of fans
let ac-e sum [a-energy] of acs

set t-light ( light-e / (60000))
set t-fan ( fan-e / (60000))
set t-ac ( ac-e / ( 60000 ) )

show (word "sum of ac energy = " ac-e )

set t-energy ( t-light + t-fan + t-ac )

end
```

**In the *'Measure runs using these reporters'* section if I am giving energy-calculation then it shows error `experiment aborted due to syntax error`.**

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: `energy-calculation` is a command procedure (`to` rather than `to-report`). It takes action, but does not report any result. "Measure runs using these reporters" requires a reporter, so the reporter's result can be recorded in the experiment results.

Comment: So how can I put this to a to-report function? So that I can run it in behavior space and get the energy calculation in each run?

Comment: I would suggest that you try it, and if you get stuck, come back, ask a new question, show your attempt, and explain what went wrong or where you got stuck.

Comment: I have already tried it and faced problems. I have also asked another question but did not get any reply.